# Java how to dial in Asterisk

Tags: java, asterisk

I want to call a number and play an audio file which is located in my computer.

There is an Asterisk server set up before. With the code in the below I managed to call a number and the extension plays a audio ("this is a test call") and hang ups. I know extension does this because the audio changes when I change it.

Maybe I can play any audio I want if I change the data in the extensions.conf. But the company I do my internship doesn't allow me to see or change Asterisk' files. So I have to do it in java.

Long story short, how can I dial a number and play the audio I want then hang up in java. I'm searching on the web for days but couldn't find anything. Please help me :(

```
public void run() throws IOException, AuthenticationFailedException,
        TimeoutException
{
    OriginateAction originateAction;
    ManagerResponse originateResponse;

    originateAction = new OriginateAction();
    originateAction.setChannel(number);
    originateAction.setContext(context);
    originateAction.setExten(extension);
    originateAction.setPriority(Integer.parseInt(priority));
    originateAction.setTimeout(new Integer(30000));

    managerConnection.login();                                              // connect to Asterisk and log in
    originateResponse = managerConnection.sendAction(originateAction, 30000);// send the originate action and wait for a maximum of 30 seconds for Asterisk to send a reply
    System.out.println(originateResponse.getResponse());                    // print out whether the originate succeeded or not
    managerConnection.logoff();                                             // and finally log off and disconnect

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/asterisk-java/asterisk-java)

You can use exec("Playback","your file") to play a file

```
public class ExampleCallIn extends BaseAgiScript {
  public void service(AgiRequest request, AgiChannel channel) throws AgiException {
    answer();
    exec("Playback", "tt-monkeys"); 
    hangup();
  }
}
```

the exec command can use any application defined by your asterisk server like Dial or Originate

Comment: I didn't know I can use exec, thank you. I tried 
public void service() throws AgiException { exec("Dial", number); exec("Playback", "tt-monkeys"); hangup(); } it seems logical to me but I get error, "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to send command from an invalid thread"

Comment: which version of asterisk does your company use? Can you ask them to change some config in the asterisk server?

Comment: Asterisk Call Manager/1.3 The usage of asterisk is not only this project so in case I mess up the working system they don't allow me to change.  For now, the thing i'm trying to is start a call with originateResponse = managerConnection.sendAction(originateAction, 30000); and right after calling your method so I can playback and hang up. Could you please help me to call your method the code I gave? I can't manage to call it :( what should I write for request and channel?

Comment: and also can you check my other question?